# Getting gradle to auto build after making code changes

Tags: java, gradle

Is there a way to add something to the 'build.gradle' file to get it to auto build upon changes made to code within a project? Or are there any tricks with gradle or java to auto compile/build you project?

Comment: Is your project an Android project? Which language are you using?

Comment: @Junior I'm just doing a Java webserver project

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `gradle --continuous myTask`.

That's a feature of the brand new [2.5 version](https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/release-notes.html#continuous-build).

> When you run with the --continuous or -t command line options, Gradle will not exit at the end of a build. Instead, Gradle will wait for files that are processed by the build to change. When changes are detected, Gradle will re-run the previous build with the same task selection.

See the [Continuous Build user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continuous_build).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Kind of surprised the "--continuous" feature page didn't show up in my Google searches, anyways thanks again!

Comment: Just to give an example, if you want to execute the task "myTask" after every code change, you would use
`gradle -t myTask`